# When I am trying to run the server by npm run server, I get this error : Error: Cannot find module './config/db'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, module

This is my server.jsx file
[server.jsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m5y2.jpg)

Here is my bd.jsx file which is in config folder
[db.jsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xog1A.jpg)

And here is my folder structure
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGIOt.jpg)

My package.json file
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVmRL.jpg)

When i try to npm run server, I get this error :
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './config/db'
Require stack:

!!!Please help someone!!!

I tried deleting node_modules and package-log.json file and installed again but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use the extension `.jsx`.

Quote from [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#file-modules):

> If the exact filename is not found, then Node.js will attempt to load the required filename with the added extensions: .js, .json, and finally .node. When loading a file that has a different extension (e.g. .cjs), its full name must be passed to require(), including its file extension (e.g. require('./file.cjs')).

Why are you using `.jsx` for server-side files anyway? JSX allows you to embed HTML tags inside JS, it's only useful for front-end and Node alone wouldn't be able to run it if you actually included JSX syntax in your files. Change them to normal `.js`.